# Recovering From No Space on Device

Tags: polkadot, nodes

Whilst running a Polkadot node, the VPS ran out of disk space.

After re-sizing the box, restarting the service gives a DB version error:

```
0: Backend error: Database version cannot be read
```

Is this recoverable, or do I need to resync from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this recoverable, or do I need to resync from scratch?

No, that is sadly not recoverable.

We have an [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/12399) open to stop the node when the disk is running full. This should in the future prevent these errors.